# Can a flying bullet be caught with your hands?

Tags: velocity

Many films show heroes catching fired bullet with their fingers. Is it practically possible?

Is it possible to do like that or just in movies? Can we catch a bullet that is fired towards catcher?

Comment: Related: http://what-if.xkcd.com/81/

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): In such type of questions, OP is encouraged to perform a crude [back of an envelope calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation) as a sanity check, and possibly include it in the post.

Comment: Are you supposing the hero is still wrt the ground?

Comment: @Michal Aahh, xkcd references <3

Comment: are those heroes superman? Because he could definitely catch the bullet. But you can't. If you tried to catch it point-first, it would take off a finger. If you tried to catch it from the side between your fingers then you could never grip it. It would be like firing a bullet through a hole the exact same diameter as the bullet (meaning friction would try to wedge it in and have it get stuck). You would not catch the bullet, you would only make the hole slightly bigger.

Comment: That all depends on the relative motion between the bullet and the target. If the bullet is travelling at 300 meters/second, and the target it travelling away from the bullet at 299.9 meters per second, then the relative velocity is 0.1 meters/second and, yes, you could then catch the bullet. However, for the common case where the bullet is travelling 300 meters/second and the target is stationary, you might call it "catching" if you define "catch" as a momentary phenomenon, followed immediately by "penetrated by". KIDS! DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME! THESE PEOPLE ARE PROFESSIONALS!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give a back of the envelope calculation. Suppose:

- Mass of the bullet:  $m = 10 \mathrm{g}$
- Speed:  $v=300 \mathrm {m/s}$
- Length:  $l =5 \mathrm{cm}$

This gives a momentum: $p=mv=3 kg \frac{m}{s} $.

You should be able to stop it in: $t =\frac{l}{v}=0.1 \mathrm{ms}$.

That means, you would have to apply a force of: $F=\frac{\Delta p }{\Delta t}=30\mathrm{kN}$

This gives an unreasonable high force. For example, a saltwater crocodile can bite with a force of $15\mathrm{kN}$.

So, even if our fingers where undestructable, we wouldn't have the force to stop it.

Let's see how much pressure would we have to make. If we suppose that the area of our fingers is: $A=1\mathrm{cm}$. The pressure would be: $P=F/A=300\mathrm{MPa}$.

This pressure is found in water jet cutters. It three times, the pressure at the bottom of the ocean.

As we can see, if we had the strength to stop the bullet, our fingers would have gone.

Comment: You do not need to stop a bullet over distance of 5 cm. You can do it over the span of your hand, that is 1 m. And given that people can SHOOT bullets, giving them this momentum in less than a second says that humans have in principle enough force to stop them.

Comment: Don't forget that the air friction heats the bullet up to very high temperatures.

Comment: Mass of bullet is about 16g for .44 magnum hand gun at ~320m/s. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_of_firearms  @Anixx the area where the energy is transfered in a holding a pistol is much larger than that area where it is transfered in the bullet's impact.  Humans do have enough force to stop them, but it often takes a few bones and a lot of tissue.

Answer (score 1):

It was said that a French pilot did this during World War I, although this is possible in principle, I can't find any reliable references about it (perhaps in French?).

The initial speed of a bullet is at least hundreds of meters per second, and catching it using fingers is incredible. But when the bullet has been flying for a period, its speed may decline to dozens of meters per second, which is roughly equivalent to the speed of a plane (at that time). Therefore, it is possible when $v_{bullet} \approx v_{plane}$ but extremely difficult in practice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is no.

The point of bullets is to kill people. If you tried, you would find the bullet goes by too fast to see, much less reach out and catch. If the bullet hit your fingers, most likely they would be shot off.

The point of movies is to entertain. An impossibly heroic hero is more entertaining than reality.

Comment: This is assuming that the bullet has just been fired (which is indeed typically the case in movies, but nowhere stated in the question). If the bullet has already lost a lot of speed due to friction or gravity, it might just be possible. Just check the what-if xkcd post that @Michal commented: http://what-if.xkcd.com/81/

Comment: Having gone hunting a few times in my life, I disagree that "the point of bullets is to kill people."

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - I did not intend that in a political sense. We can include animals and other targets. I just meant that they are weapons, and very bad for fingers.

Answer (score 1):

A bullet's path is affected by gravity.  This means that if you shoot a bullet off into the distance as assuming there are no obstructions, the horizontal velocity could still be high enough (after a mile for example) to cause damage by the time it hits the ground.  Of course, the ballistic path of the bullet can vary quite a bit and change the speed upon which the bullet hits.  The TV reality show (USA?) called Myth Busters actually did the experiment of shooting bullets straight up in the air to determine whether they could kill someone when the bullet came back to the ground.  I think their results were inconclusive in general but if the bullet is shot straight up, its velocity on return could kill a person if they were hit by the bullet.